# How to format double or trailing slashes in comments?

Tags: support, comments

I've came across this problem today. In a comment it seems not possible to format `\\` correctly. This happens every time a `\` it at the end.

```
`//`     <--   is fine in comments
`\\`     <--   will just print '`\`', without highlight
`test\`  <--   will just print '`test`', without highlight
```

Is it a bug? Or is there a way to format things like this correctly in comments? In questions and answers it is no problem, as seen above.